# How can I automatically increase Sheet number when referencing external workbook?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a formula in Workbook1 that automatically pulls data from Workbook2.  There is a new tab for each day in Workbook2 and are named Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, etc.  My ideal formula would pull the data using vlookup, while automatically incrementing the Sheet number by one each time I autofill the formula one column to the right.

Here is the current formula I have in Workbook1 to pull the data from Workbook2.

A1

```
(VLOOKUP("JohnSmith",'[Workbook2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$50:$O$79,3,FALSE)
```

B1

```
(VLOOKUP("JohnSmith",'[Workbook2.xlsx]Sheet2'!$A$50:$O$79,3,FALSE)
```

C1

```
(VLOOKUP("JohnSmith",'[Workbook2.xlsx]Sheet3'!$A$50:$O$79,3,FALSE)
```

Comment: The only way to do what you want without vba is to use INDIRECT as TimWilliams stated.  But that means the other workbook must be open, as you pointed out.

Comment: Thank you for the information!  If it's truly the only way to do it I can work around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In A1:

```
VLOOKUP("JohnSmith",INDIRECT("'[Workbook2.xlsx]Sheet" & COLUMN() & "'!$A$50:$O$79"),3,FALSE)
```

Comment: This may work for what I need.  The only issue is that Workbook2 may not be open when making updates to Workbook1 which might break the formula.